# SQL Server Percentage Calculation

Tags: sql-server, function

I am trying to come up with a uniform way to calculate percentage differences between two columns in a single table.
Sometimes num1 is zero, in which case the calculated difference should be 100%.
Sometimes num2 is zero, in which case the calculated difference should be 100%.
Sometimes the differences between num1 and num2 are very large, in which case the calculated difference would be 100%.

Here is a sample extract from the table:

```
declare @numtable table ( num1 decimal(10,3) , num2 decimal(10,3) )
insert into @numtable values ( 160 , 161.5 )
insert into @numtable values ( 439 , 377 )
insert into @numtable values ( 100 , 1 )
insert into @numtable values ( 1 , 100 )
insert into @numtable values ( 0 , 20 ) 
insert into @numtable values ( 20 , 0 )
```

I made a broken select statement that looks like the following.

```
select num1 , num2 , Abs(100- ( 100 * cast( cast(num1 as decimal(6,3)) / cast(num2 as decimal(10,3) ) as decimal(6,3) ) ) ) as percentdiff
from @numtable
```

Which makes this:

```
num1         num2         percentdiff
------------ ------------ -------------
160.000      161.500      0.900
439.000      377.000      16.400
100.000      1.000        9900.000
1.000        100.000      99.000
0.000        20.000       100.000
```

The first 3 rows are OK. 
The fifth row row is OK.
The sixth row never shows because it generates a divide by zero error.

I want my result set to look like this:

```
num1         num2         percentdiff
------------ ------------ -------------
160.000      161.500      0.900
439.000      377.000      16.400
100.000      1.000        9900.000
1.000        100.000      9900.000
0.000        20.000       100.000
20.000       20.000       100.000
```

How should I change my select into something that returns the way I need it?

Thanks.

Comment: The comments next to each insert shows what happens for each row and what I want it to show. Is there a better way to present that?

Comment: Did you notice you declared `num2` as an `int` and then tried to insert `161.5`?

Comment: you say "insert into numtable values ( 100 , 1 ) should return 100 " and then you say: "insert into numtable values ( 1 , 100 ) should return 100" How is it possible that both those things should return 100? :)

Comment: It's returning correctly... Why do you think it should return 100?

Comment: I am not trying to just divide two numbers, but determine what the percentage difference is between the two numbers, with a special case where divide by zero means one number is 100% different from zero.

Comment: @Snowy modified my answer to account for your edit.

Comment: @Snowy I removed my comment per your edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a case statement in your third item of your select list to test for a divide by 0 error. In the else do your math. It's that simple.

```
Select num1, num2,
 Case num2
 WHEN 0 Then 100
 Else Abs(100- ( 100 * cast( cast(num1 as decimal(6,3)) / cast(num2 as decimal(10,3) ) as decimal(6,3) ) ) ) 
 END as percentdiff

From @numtable
```

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f2717/1).

You just need to do a bit extra at the *divide by zero* case:

`case when num1 <= 0 or num2 <= 0 or num1 = num2 then 100`

```
select num1,num2,
case when num1 <= 0 or num2 <= 0 or num1 = num2 then 100
  else
   case when 
   cast(
     cast(abs(num1-num2) as decimal(8,5))
     /
     cast(case when num1>num2 then num2 else num1 end as decimal(8,5))
     * 100
   as decimal(8,2))
   > 100 then
     9900 
   else
    cast(
     cast(abs(num1-num2) as decimal(8,5))
     /
     cast(case when num1>num2 then num2 else num1 end as decimal(8,5))
     * 100
   as decimal(8,2))
   end
  end as percentage
from t
```